# Find out the size of a lookup table in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

Is there a way to determine the number of `message` elements in the following look-up table or do I need to explicitly have an `int size` in the struct?

```
typedef struct {
    int enable;
    char* message[3];
} lookuptable;

lookuptable table[] = {
    {1, {"Foo", "Bar", "Baz"}}, // # 3
    {1, {"Foo", "Bar"}},        // # 2
    {1, {"Foo"}},               // # 1
    {1, {"Foo", "Baz"}},        // # 2
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is no way to do that. You will have to store the number of elements somewhere or terminate the array with a magic number or a NULL.

Answer (score 1):

There will always be exactly 3 message elements in the message array, because you have defined it as having a size of 3.  Those elements of the array you don't initialize will be initialized to NULL, so you can loop through the initialized (non-null) elements with:

```
lookuptable *table_entry = ...
for (int i = 0; i < 3 && table_entry->message[i]; i++) {
    ...do something...
```

It might be a good idea to replace the constant `3` with a `#define` constant, so it only exists in one place.  Or you could use the `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` trick:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizoef(table_entry->message)/sizeof(table_entry->message[0]) && table_entry->message[i]; i++)
```